# CSS file in ASP.NET

Tags: css, stylesheet

I know this is a simple question but for some reason I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong here.

My understanding is that if you **declare 2 CSS** files

```
<script type="text/css" src="JQueryUI.css"></script>     
<script type="text/css" src="Override.css"></script>
```

I want to use the "Override.css" to override some values, so if I type let's say ".ui-accordion" and put my own values, i would expect them to take priority over the original values located under that name on the JQuery.css file.

Mainly because the **declaration states** that Override.css comes **AFTER** JWuery.css.

**For some reason this is NOT happening**.

I tried switching the declaration of the 2 files
...but the Jquery.css seems to **ALWAYS** seems to take priority.

Any reason why ??

Comment: The selectors in jQueryUI.css may have a higher specificity. Have a look at [this link](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Comment: OK...do you know how to change that and simply tell "anything on my override.css" file has higher specificity than ... ?

Comment: You would actually have to give your selectors in your Override.css file a higher specificity. Or, give your Override.css file the *exact same* selectors as your JQueryUI.css file, *and* make sure Override.css is loaded *after* JQueryUI.css. Another option is to use `!important`, which would be the "quick and dirty" way of doing it (not recommended).

Comment: this is the 1s time i hear about Specificity. Not sure how to specify a higher one on the Override.css element (or event better on the entire file). Regarding loading, isn't it enough to specify it after on the declaration ?

Comment: btw are you really using `<script>` tags to attach CSS files? Has it ever worked?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what I mean by specificity. Please read through the link I provided in my first comment. As an example, `ul#nav` would **always** have a higher specificity than `#nav`, **even though they would only ever target one element**. This is because `ul#nav` is more *specific* than `#nav`. Also, @haynar is right - you should be using `link` tags instead of `script` tags (I hadn't noticed this before).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not working because you are not loading correctly the css files.

It should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="JQueryUI.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Override.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I am agree with Zhihao about specificity of elements, but I have also noticed that your are using `<script>` to attach CSS files, use `<link>` tags instead, maybe that would load your css and it will override existing styles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="JQueryUI.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Override.css" />
```

P.S. just posted my notice in the comment as an answer